# Send input disabled Data

Tags: php, jquery, html

I have a form with input text; I change this input dynamically with `JQuery` to disabled - but sometimes I put something in this input and I disable it.  When I send this form I don't have this input with my data

How can I get the value of this input even if it is disabled:

```
<input type="text" id="myInput" name="myInput"/>
```

JQuery :

```
$('#Checkbox').change(function() {
    if ($('#myInput').prop("disabled")) {
        $("#myInput").prop('disabled', false);
    } else {
        $("#myInput").prop('disabled', true);
    }    
});
```

Comment: why use disable ? use readonly instead

Comment: Your question doesn't make much sense regarding the poor context you provided

Answer (score 3):

A `readonly` element is just not editable, but gets sent when the according form submits. a `disabled` element isn't editable and isn't sent on submit.

So instead of making it `disabled` change it to `readonly`

```
$('#Checkbox').change(function() {
  if($('#myInput').prop("readonly")) {
     $( "#myInput" ).prop('readonly', false);
  } else{
     $( "#myInput" ).prop('readonly', true);
  }
});
```

Comment: Ya and a simple styling rule would give it the appearence of a disabled element, if that really matters

Answer (score 0):

You can do this by adding a hidden field underneath with the value you want to POST.

```
<input type="text" id="myInput" name="myInput"/>
<input type="hidden" id="myInputHidden" name="myInput"/>
```

then

```
$('#Checkbox').change(function() {

    $("#myInputHidden").val($("#myInput").val());

    if ($('#myInput').prop("disabled")) {
        $( "#myInput" ).prop('disabled', false);
    }
    else {
        $( "#myInput" ).prop('disabled', true);
    }
});
```

When the form POSTs, the value for 'myInput' will be the text field if it's enabled and the hidden field if the text field is disabled.